# Json Parsing with same header name produces Error

Tags: android, json, gson

I have a `json` where there are products and categories. The keyword product comes under the categories as well. The `json` is

```
{
"categories": [
    {
        "id": "categoryA",
        "name": "Coffees",
        "products": [
            "productA",
            "productC",
            "productE",
            "productF"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "categoryB",
        "name": "Extra Coffees",
        "products": [
            "productB",
            "productG",
            "productA"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "categoryC",
        "name": "Small Coffees",
        "products": [
            "productA",
            "productG",
            "productE"
        ]
    }
],
"products": [
    {
        "id": "productA",
        "name": "Coffe A",
        "price": 350
    },
    {
        "id": "productB",
        "name": "Coffe B",
        "price": 450
    },
    {
        "id": "productC",
        "name": "Coffe C",
        "price": 150
    },
    {
        "id": "productD",
        "name": "Coffe D",
        "price": 250
    },
    {
        "id": "productE",
        "name": "Coffe E",
        "price": 500
    },
    {
        "id": "productF",
        "name": "Coffe F",
        "price": 325
    },
    {
        "id": "productG",
        "name": "Coffe G",
        "price": 315
    },
    {
        "id": "productH",
        "name": "Coffe H",
        "price": 350
    }
]}
```

I have created the following two classes for Product and Categories Like this.

### Categories

```
public class Categories {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<String> products;

    public String getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

### Products

```
public class Products {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private double price = 0;

    public String getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return this.price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

Now I have created another class which I use for parsing from Json to Entity. That class is:

```
public class CategoriesProducts {
    private ArrayList<Categories> categories;
    private ArrayList<Products> products;
}
```

When I try to parse there comes an error: `Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 299.`
I am parsing the json by the following line of code.

```
Categories cat = GsonFactory.getConfiguredGson().fromJson(abc , Categories.class);
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can we see the parsing code?

Comment: Categories cat = GsonFactory.getConfiguredGson().fromJson(abc , Categories.class);

Comment: That's the problem, see Egor answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
CategoriesProducts catProd = GsonFactory.getConfiguredGson().fromJson(abc, CategoriesProducts.class);
```

Where `abc` is the `String` containg JSON.